# How to check connection to a list of servers in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, ssh

Im trying to check connections for a list of servers. I want to loop through the list, check if a connection works and if yes, do some stuff, if not, echo out a problem message.

My problem is:
the script stops at the first node without echoing the $?.
So, whats wrong with my for-loop?

These vars are included from a config file:
`$nodes` is a list of server IPs like `1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,10.10.10.10`
`$user` is one string

```
for node in $(echo $nodes | sed "s/,/ /g")
    do
    echo "Checking Node: $node"

    ssh -q -o ConnectTimeout=3 $user@$node echo ok
    echo $?
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Problem in logging into $node"
    else
        # do some stuff here
    fi
done
```

**EDIT #1:**

```
for node in $(echo $nodes | sed "s/,/ /g")
    do
    echo "Checking Node: $node"

    ssh -q -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 $user@$node "echo ok"
    retcode=$?
    echo $retcode
    if [[ "$retcode" -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Problem in logging into $node"
    else
        echo "OK"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-t`to make virtual terminal and add quotes on command:

```
ssh -q -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 ${user}@${node} "echo ok"
```

Also use `-ne` instead of `!=` which is for compare strings

```
if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]
```

Also `echo $?` mess the return code. You should use something like:

```
ssh -q -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 ${user}@${node} "echo ok"
retcode=$?
echo $retcode
if [[ "$retcode" -ne 0 ]]
```

You can rewrite `ssh` command like this to avoid problems with `ssh` host keys

```
ssh -q -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=3 ${user}@${node} "echo ok"
```

Comment: @xMaNuu, please check again my suggestions about `$?`

Comment: Oh sorry, i changed my code to this `if [[ "$retcode" -ne 0 ]]`. See my edited code above. but anyway, this does not work. if the 1st node is not reachable, the complete script stops. i would expect that the script iterates to the next node in my list.

Comment: i dont think that would help. in my case there is no host key checking, because the machine is just not reachable. It's a fake ip i try to connect. But exactly in this case, i want to get an error for this particular ip and go on with the next ip of my list.

Comment: @xMaNuu, there is timeout. So you can run the script and wait

Answer (score 0):

It is because ssh first asks you to validate *The authority of the host* and If you accept the authority it will ask for password. That is why your command does not return to shell and waits for input.

If your intention is just validating ssh connection, then you may consider to use

```
telnet <your_host> <port> < /dev/null
```

But if your intend is to run some commands you need a trust relationship between hosts. In that case you can use:

Execute this commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

then

```
ssh-copy-id -i root@ip_address
```

Now you can connect with

```
ssh <user>@<host>
```

[Furher information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

Comment: Actually, all hosts i try to reach are already in my "known host list". Authentication is always done via key, so no password is required. Just for testing my script i put a unvalid ip in my list. this server does not exist in real. But it could be the situation that one of my valid server IPs are not reachable or something like that. so i would expect that ssh throws an error, if a connection cant be established.